# Inverse Laplace Transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{s+a}+\sqrt{s+b}}$

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

I need to calculate the inverse laplace of:
$$F(s)=[\frac{1}{\sqrt{s+a}+\sqrt{s+b}}] \qquad \qquad  (s>-a\quad ;\quad  s>-b;\quad a\neq b) $$

Answer (score 4):

Note that by multiplying the numerator and the denominator of $F(s)$ by $\sqrt{s+a}-\sqrt{s+b}$ you get

$$F(s)=\frac{\sqrt{s+a}-\sqrt{s+b}}{a-b}\tag{1}$$

The inverse Laplace transform of $\sqrt{s+a}$ can be found in [tables](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/LapInv3.pdf):

$$\sqrt{s+a}\leftrightarrow -\frac{e^{-at}}{2 \sqrt{\pi t^3}}\tag{2}$$

With $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get for the inverse transform of $F(s)$

$$F(s)\leftrightarrow \frac{e^{-bt}-e^{-at}}{2(a-b) \sqrt{\pi t^3}}\tag{3}$$